# Resolving types of classes to be put into the declaration and instantiation of a generic object at runtime

Tags: java, generics, runtime

Take this code that doesn't work, but is so far my best attempt at solving the problem.

```
String keyType = args[0];
String valueType = args[1];

Class<?> resolvedKeyType;
Class<?> resolvedValueType;

if (keyType.equals("I")) {
    resolvedKeyType = Integer.class;
}
else if (keyType.equals("D")) {
    resolvedKeyType = Double.class;
}
else if (keyType.equals("S")) {
    resolvedKeyType = String.class;
}

if (valueType.equals("I")) {
    resolvedValueType = Integer.class;
}
else if (valueType.equals("D")) {
    resolvedValueType = Double.class;
}
else if (valueType.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    resolvedValueType = String.class;
}

KVCollection<resolvedKeyType, resolvedValueType> data = new KVCollection<resolvedKeyType, resolvedValueType>();
```

This doesn't work, and on the last line I get the error (paraphrased) `resolvedKeyType/resolvedValueType cannot be resolved to a type.` My question revolves around how I would be able to instantiate an object that uses generics at runtime so that I can pick what type of data (Integer, Double, String) will be used in an object that uses generics at runtime based on user input? Is this simply not possible or am I taking the wrong approach? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You cannot. Read up on [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You could potentially use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: As was explained by me previously in your deleted question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, I probably should have read the comments, but I deleted it to solve the XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but have you tried

```
Object resolvedKeyType;
resolvedKeyType = new Integer(0);
```